# Allow Administrators to impersonate users using an iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, iframe, admin

I have an MVC project with three roles: Users, Account Managers, and Administrators.

Administrators have their own MVC Area where they have full control over Users and Account Managers. I'm trying to implement functionality to allow Administrators to view the site as any User or Account Manager.

In the Admin Area of the site, I have a View of a list of Users and Account Managers. The list contains a "View Site As User" button for each record.

I have never done anything like this before, but the `ViewAs` Controller Action is currently set up to create a Session with the selected User's information, like so:

```
ViewBag.SiteSession = Session["SiteSession"] = new SiteSession()
{
    ID = user.ID,
    AccountID = user.AccountID,
    DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
    IsManager = user.IsAdmin,
    IsAdmin = false
};
```

The View relevant to this Action has the Model defined as a `string`, and nothing else but an iframe with the Model as the `src` attribute, like so:

```
@model string
<iframe src="@Model" >

</iframe>
```

What I'm trying to do is render whichever portion of the site was requested in this iframe. When an Administrator clicks "View As User," I'd like to direct to Home. The URL is generated through this call:

```
Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = "" }));
```

The Area is set to nothing to avoid rendering the Admin Area's Home.

Currently, this is not working. I don't know where to even begin, minus what I already have.

I'm looking for any suggestions. All help is greatly appreciated, as this doesn't seem like an easy task.

If you don't know how to help, it would also be appreciated if you could direct this question to somebody that can.

Again, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task, I ended up creating a separate controller, `ViewAsController`, which had a controller-wide `[Authorize]` attribute that only allowed users with the Admin role to access its actions.

In the `Start` action, a `Session` object containing the selected User's information is created, like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Start(int id)
{
    var user = db.Users
        .First(u => u.ID == id);

    Session["SiteSession"] = new SiteSession()
    {
        //Session data...
    };

    return PartialView("_IFrame");
}
```

This Action returns a Partial View that I ended up displaying in a jQuery UI modal dialog window.

Here's the code for that Partial View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.SiteSession = (SiteSession)Session["SiteSession"];
}
<h2>Viewing Site As @ViewBag.SiteSession.DisplayName</h2>
<div>
    <iframe src="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = "" })"></iframe>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's extremely bare, and that's exactly what it needs to be. The `<iframe>` acts as a browser in a browser, allowing the Admin user full access to whichever Actions the selected User would.

For the sake of detail, here's the jQuery that creates the dialog and opens it:

```
$(function () {
    $("#viewAsDialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        draggable: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        height: $(window).height() * .9,
        width: 1000,
        closeText: '',
        close: function () {
            $.post("@Url.Action("End", "ViewAs", new { Area = "Admin" })")
                    .success(function (result) {
                    });
        }
    });
});

function viewAs(result) {
    $("#viewAsDialog").html(result);
    $("#viewAsDialog").dialog("open");
}
```

You can see here that the dialog is initialized on document-ready, and is not opened until the AJAX call that retrieves the Partial View is successfully completed.

Once the Admin closes the dialog, the server calls the `End` action in the `ViewAs` Controller, destroying the session:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult End()
{
    Session["SiteSession"] = null;

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way that I've done this in the past has been to use the concept of an an actual user and an effective user. Most display actions use the effective user to generate their content. Typically I've implemented it as "impersonation" rather than "preview" so the user is actually navigating the site as the user rather than displaying in a separate window. In this case I simply set both in the current session. Things that require admin permission (like switching to/from impersonation) obviously use the real user.

If you wanted to do preview then I'd think about using a parameter on each request to set the   effective user. The code would need to understand to add this parameter to all links so that you could navigate in the `iframe` without messing up navigation in the original interface.

As for removing the area from the url, I think what you have (setting to the empty string) should work. If it's not working you might want to try lowercase `area`, `Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })`. I'm pretty sure that the `RouteValueDictionary` that gets created under the hood uses a case insensitive key comparison, though, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I called it "preview" since you're displaying in separately in an iframe while keeping the original interface intact.  Maybe my terminology is wrong, but what I mean by impersonation would be that you'd simply change the original interface to display as the impersonated user (with the ability to stop impersonation being the only difference). Impersonating side-by-side seems harder since there's no way on the server, without a request parameter, to tell the difference between requests from the iframe/enclosing window.